# Sketch 3 Text Wrap

Tags: website-design, interface-design, sketch-app, text-wrap

Does anyone know how to create a text wrap in Sketch 3. I've scoured the internet and the best solution I've found is "use different text boxes" which does not seem ideal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*"You can't get there from here."*

This is a **GLARING** omission from an otherwise excellent app, which should include the layout capabilities of all basic CSS. Float/wrap is intrinsic to web layout and way too difficult to achieve as a mockup in Sketch the way it's currently (not) implemented. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

In your text settings, set the Width to fixed.

[image]

Then you can drag the box to arrange your column width.

You could also *draw* a box with the Text tool before you type/paste in your copy. This would set *Width* to *Fixed* automatically.

Comment: But neither of those achieves what the OP was inquiring about: a text *wrap*.